# how to prevent index of /errors from htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

Hello I am using `Codeigniter` and I do not have folder named errors I do not have controller named errors I do not have `errors.php` in my root
But whenever I type URL like **`www.example.org/errors/`** it will return

### Index of /errors

```
Parent Directory
SingleDomainHosting.php
sdh-403.html
sdh-404.html
sdh-500.html
sdh-suspended.html
```

I tried `Options -Indexes` and `IndexIgnore *`  in my `.htaccess` but I can't find any solution.

this is in my `routes.php`

```
$route['default_controller'] ='webcontroller';
$route['404_override'] = 'webcontroller/errorpage';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['mycms/page/about-us'] = "mycms/webcontroller/page/about-us";



//$route['page/(:any)'] = 'webcontroller/page/$1';
$route['(:any)'] = 'webcontroller/page/$1';
$route['post/(:any)'] = 'webcontroller/post/$1';
$route['event/(:any)'] = 'webcontroller/event/$1';
$route['event/allevents'] = 'webcontroller/event/allevents';
```

I can't understand what is this? 
What can I do for this?

Comment: have you checked routes ?

Comment: @DevsiOdedra Please see my updated answer

Comment: something from your hosting provider maybe?

Comment: If you just don't want people to be able to navigate to `/errors` you should add a line to your htaccess to have requests to that url return a 404. Probably a better idea than potentially breaking how codeignitor works just because you don't want that url to return an index page.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^errors/$ - [L,R=404]`. That way any requests to `errors/sdh-403.html` or similar still work (assuming they exist for a reason and need to be accessible to the web browser).

Answer (score 0):

i suspect that your web server directory has an alias route in the conf file, in this case /error as apache has it. beside the Option -indexes problem